# Apache Util.copyStream: Stop Stream

Tags: java, apache, file-transfer

Is it possible to stop the bytesTransferred stream for the Apache Util.copyStream function?

```
long bytesTransferred = Util.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream, 32768, CopyStreamEvent.UNKNOWN_STREAM_SIZE, new CopyStreamListener() {
    @Override
    public void bytesTransferred(CopyStreamEvent event) {
        bytesTransferred(event.getTotalBytesTransferred(), event.getBytesTransferred(), event.getStreamSize());
    }
    @Override
    public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred, int bytesTransferred,
                                 long streamSize) {
        try {
            if(true) {
               log.info('Stopping');
               return; //Cancel
            } else {
              log.info('Still going');
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // this should not happen!
        }
    }
});
```

In this case, what will happen is that I keep getting a Stopping message in my logs. I also tried throwing a new RuntileException instead of returning, and again I get endless Stopping messages. How would I cancel the bytesTransfered in this case?

Comment: per his OP, he did try that.

Comment: Throwing an exception does the same thing. I will get the Stopping message over and over again

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the input stream, and overriding the read methods to check for a stop flag. If set, throw an IOException. Example class.

```
/**
 * Wrapped input stream that can be cancelled.
 */
public class WrappedStoppableInputStream extends InputStream
{
    private InputStream m_wrappedInputStream;

    private boolean m_stop = false;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param inputStream original input stream
     */
    public WrappedStoppableInputStream(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        m_wrappedInputStream = inputStream;
    }

    /**
     * Call to stop reading stream.
     */
    public void cancelTransfer()
    {
        m_stop = true;
    }


    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException
    {
        if (m_stop)
        {
            throw new IOException("Stopping stream");
        }

        return m_wrappedInputStream.read();
    }


    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException
    {
        if (m_stop)
        {
            throw new IOException("Stopping stream");
        }

        return m_wrappedInputStream.read(b);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
    {
        if (m_stop)
        {
            throw new IOException("Stopping stream");
        }

        return m_wrappedInputStream.read(b, off, len);
    }
}
```

I am assuming that the file copying is running inside a thread. So you wrap your input stream with WrappedStoppableInputStream, and pass that to your copy function, to be used instead of the original input stream.